# Will every Python statement involved dictionary make a hash table research?

Tags: python

Python is a kind of "script" programming language.
In this situation:

```
def dic_test():
    a={}
    a[0]=[0,0,0]
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[0][0]+=1
        a[0][1]+=1
        a[0][2]+=1
    print(a)

def no_dic_test():
    a={}
    a[0]=[0,0,0]
    target=a[0]
    for i in range(10000000):
        target[0]+=1
        target[1]+=1
        target[2]+=1
    print(a)
```

Will `no_dic_test()` be faster than `dic_test()`?
I thought Yes. Because, Python is dynamical. Each statement will be translated separately.

I used profile to benchmark. The first function was slower than second one, but the different was slight.

First function: 5 function calls in 26.113 seconds

Second function: 5 function calls in 23.835 seconds

That is a extreme case. In my own case, like 10k keys, 10k times operations, direct use of a dictionary will be faster. I am so surprised.

To end, is there "static compiler" like C or cache optimisation in Python for Dictionary? or are Python hash table just too fast to face the problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `print` statements when profiling. When using pythons `timeit` I consistently get faster results for the `dic_test`. [Check out the results](http://bpaste.net/show/sFmmqFGOCoh11UGdtOmE/).

Comment: Yes. It does. Remove print. Thanks for comment! How can I close this stupid question.

Comment: it's not a dumb question - python is not C, so you should not make the same assumptions about profiling python as C.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its pretty obvious that the second function is doing far less work on each loop.

The first function will have to do a dict lookup and local store for each loop where as the second function does this once.

There are runtimes like PyPy that spot the hot loop and JIT compile them for added performance, but the CPython runtime doesn't do this kind of optimisation yet.